# I have a string with data i want to store this string file into xml. what should i do?

Tags: android, xml

i have a string which contain..

```
<response type="1">
<terminal_id>1000099999</terminal_id>
<merchant_id>10004444</merchant_id>
<merchant_info>Mc Donald's - Abdoun</merchant_info>
<transaction_id>7777771</transaction_id>
<process_status>1</process_status>
<process_status_desc>Success</process_status_desc>
<process_date>30/06/2011 12:39:32</process_date>
<menu_version_id>1</menu_version_id>
<menu>
<menu type="campaigns">
<menu campaign_id="1" title_en="2nd sandwich free" title_ar="??????? ????? ??????">
<menu>
</menu>
<specific_inputs>
<input_item key="amount" type="float" title_en="Amount" title_ar="??????"/>
</specific_inputs>
</menu>
</menu>
<menu type="fixed_text" id="1" title_en="Help" title_ar="??????">
<text_en>When making sales, first the campaign should be selected. Then the </text_en>
<text_ar>When making sales, first the
</text_ar>
</menu>
<menu type="fixed_text" id="2" title_en="Support" title_ar="???">
<text_en>Mobilera: 06-583 3500 or 06-583 3400</text_en>

<text_ar>Mobilera: 06-583 3500 or 06-583 3400</text_ar>
</menu>
</menu>
</response>

<response type="1">
<terminal_id>1000099999</terminal_id>
<merchant_id>10004444</merchant_id>
<merchant_info>Mc Donald's - Abdoun</merchant_info>
<transaction_id>7777771</transaction_id>
<process_status>1</process_status>
<process_status_desc>Success</process_status_desc>
<process_date>30/06/2011 12:39:32</process_date>
<menu_version_id>1</menu_version_id>
<menu>

<menu type="campaigns">
<menu campaign_id="1" title_en="2nd sandwich free" title_ar="??????? ????? ??????">
<menu>
</menu>
<specific_inputs>
<input_item key="amount" type="float" title_en="Amount" title_ar="??????"/>
</specific_inputs>
</menu>
</menu>
<menu type="fixed_text" id="1" title_en="Help" title_ar="??????">
<text_en>When making sales, first the campaign should be selected. Then the </text_en>
<text_ar>When making sales, first the
</text_ar>
</menu>
<menu type="fixed_text" id="2" title_en="Support" title_ar="???">
<text_en>Mobilera: 06-583 3500 or 06-583 3400</text_en>

<text_ar>Mobilera: 06-583 3500 or 06-583 3400</text_ar>
</menu>
</menu>
</response>
```

how can this string data store into xml.

Comment: Isn't this already XML? I think maybe this question needs clarifcation.

Comment: @DrG i had arrange string like xml i want to store this as xml what should i do?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: but i want just to take the element name. and should i make this string as new.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tryed:

```
String xmlRecords = "<data>string</data>";

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document d1 = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlRecords)));
```

it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to create xml file from your string

```
String str = //your xml file
byte[] stringInByte = str.getBytes();

File myxmlFile = new File(path of file+"mydata.xml"); //mydata.xml is the name of file //that you want to create

            // write the bytes in file
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(myxmlFile);
            fo.write(stringInByte);
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: i want to store in my assets then what will be  my path.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Java question. If I understood you corretly you just have to save the String  into a file as http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-write-to-file.shtml

Comment: I want to store above] containt in xxx.xml file.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: look bro, this whole contain the comes to me as string. i want to store this string as xml file.